# Looping through a list and returning the list inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to return a list, I am getting different results when i return

```
def list_book():
    lines = [['eofih', 'sdf', 'False'], ['sfdds', 'afds', 'False']]

    books = [{"name": line[0], "author": line[1], "read": line[2]}
        for line in lines
    ]
    return books
```

This returns perfectly :

```
[{'name': 'eofih', 'author': 'sdf', 'read': 'False'},{'name': 'sfdds', 'author': 'afds', 'read': 'False'}]
```

But when i try doing as below :

```
def list_book():
    lines = [['eofih', 'sdf', 'False'], ['sfdds', 'afds', 'False']]
    
    for line in lines:
        books = [{"name": line[0], "author": line[1], "read": line[2]}]

    return books
```

This returns only the last entry in the list:

```
    [{'name': 'sfdds', 'author': 'afds', 'read': 'False'}]
```

Please let me know is it possible to return the whole list in second option.

Comment: What is the problem with the first code? If you already know that it does what you want, why don't you use it?

Comment: The answer basically is "change it to the first code".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def list_book():
    lines = [['eofih', 'sdf', 'False'], ['sfdds', 'afds', 'False']]
    books = []
    for line in lines:
        books += [{"name": line[0], "author": line[1], "read": line[2]}]

    return books
```